# Redshift is missing in target database list of AWS SCT Schema Convertion Tool

Tags: aws, redshift, amazon-dms

I want to convert schema of SQL Server database to Amazon Redshift using AWS SCT tool

But as target database, Redshift is not listed

When I use PostgreSQL compatible with IP address of the cluster, I experience a lot of Telemetry errors in the log

Any help is appretiated much
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, Amazon Redshift is only valid as a target database when you select OLAP or dataware house project option. If the project is created for an OLTP database Redshift is not an option as a target data platform.
Please refer to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/SchemaConversionTool/latest/userguide/CHAP_Welcome.html for detailed list